# facebook offline access using c#

Tags: c#, facebook

i am developing a notification service in c# for our web site. its windows service no ui (asp.net / winform). This service will run on certain time and post something on users wall. i use social plug-in in our web site where user can grant required permission. Based on this i have few question

1) is there any c# library or sdk available for Facebook.
2) what information i have to store in order to access facebook offline.

i hope my question is clear. thanks for any help.

**Update 1: i really need help on this. thanks once again.**

Comment: By offline I think you mean without the user? Not offline as in not connected to the internet.

Comment: Facebook defines 'offline access' as being able to access the users info even when they aren't specifically logged in to facebook or your application.

Comment: @ShaneC yes but once user grant permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found this one and its helpful 
http://blog.theunical.com/facebook-integration/simple-5-steps-to-publish-on-a-facebook-wall-using-dotnet-c/

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a facebook API that can be used, http://developers.facebook.com/
2. You can't access facebook offline? I mean, if you wanted to save current information while online and then re-access the old information while offline that is possible just by saving the webpages, but you cannot access any new information. so your not really accessing facebook..

Comment: thanks tommy. but i dont have any webpages. my notification service runs separately from my web site.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the user to log in, and there's a permission you can request that makes the session you get permanent.  You'll have to have some kind of installer or something that will have the user log in, grant that permission, and then you'll save that access token.  UI-wise, look at digsby, and notice how they make you log in to facebook the first time you link your facebook account.

Comment: i do have website where user can login using their FB account. once they sigin in my backend windowservice should be able to post something to users wall while user is not logged into my site.